# Saving dynamically generated data in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

Please have a look at the below image

[image: http://teamtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/check_boxes_with_javascipt_01.jpg]

Imagine you are creating a database for students, and one table is "Sport". As in the above GUI image, students can select the sports they like to play and click the save button (Keep in mind, they can select multiple). Once the button is clicked, the data will be saved in "Sport" table. Now the problem comes in, read below carefully.

Here is how I will save these data in the `Sport` table.

***Create columns in `Sport` table for every single sport listed in the GUI, with datatype boolean. Once the sports are selected in the GUI and the `Save` button is clicked, assign `true` to the related columns.***

However imagine there is a new requirement. That is, if the **sports** the student like is not in the GUI, there should be a button which allow the student to generate check box for a custom sport he like. He can add as much as possible. So the student simply added 3 custom checkboxes, *Karate*, *Swimming* and *cricket*. He also has ticked *Golf* and *Rugby* too, which is already existing in the system.

Now my question is, `how and where do I save these custom sports?` should i call a statement and generate another 3 columns for Karate, Swimming and Cricket in `Sport` table, but I don't like it I am sure it is not the way. That method will cause lot of problems.

I appreciate your advice.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to have a separate column for each sport? at the moment it just sounds like bad database design is your problem.

Comment: @GB: No specific reason. Specially because it is better than saving an array in one single column.

Comment: yeah, don't do that either. Just have one row in your table for each user sport combo. when you select from that table for that user you will get as many rows as the number of sports the user selected initially. there is already an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another database structure.
Id ¦ studentId ¦ Sport
Would be a better structure. Then you create a new row for each Sport he likes. Then he can add as much row as he wants

Comment: So that means if the student selected 15 sports (with custom sports of course), I have to execute 15 `insert into` statements?

Comment: @JustCause No, you can insert multiple records with one insert statement.